# Why does the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(1)^k}{k^2+k}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

In my homework for Differential Equations, we are determining interval of convergence for a given series.

I've gotten the radius of convergence and found the unconfirmed interval of convergence ($R=\frac{1}{3}$ and $0\lt{x}\lt{\frac{2}{3}}$).

The original summation is:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(3x-1)^k}{k^2+k}$$

I'm now trying to test the bounds of the IOC. 
The lower bound of the IOC converges (0).

However, when I plug in the upper bound ($\frac{2}{3}$) I get:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(1)^k}{k^2+k}$$

I know (or believe) I'm now supposed to take $\lim_{k\to\infty}$ of that sum, but $1^\infty$ is indeterminate, so how does that work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we have, 
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(1)^k}{k^2+k} \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}$$
we know that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}$ converges. Hence, by comparison test,$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(1)^k}{k^2+k}$ converges

Comment: Never mind... because it's in the denominator.  Duh.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1)^k}{k^2+k}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2+k}\leq \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}$$

Since $\frac{(1)^k}{k^2+k}$ is positive, increasing, and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1)^k}{k^2+k}$ bounded $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1)^k}{k^2+k}$ is convergent.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2+k}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)\\[8pt]
&=1
\end{align}
$$